# From parameter in email is showing Hosting providers email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, email-headers

I'm using codeigniter 2.X and my app is hosted on Justhost,
App was working fine till few days back when justhost upgraded the server, After upgrade outgoing emails are showing wrong From email address.

here is debug output after from the app

```
User-Agent: Codeigniter
Date: Tue, 10 Jul 2012 03:54:17 -0600
From: "example.com" 
Return-Path: 
Reply-To: "example.com" 
X-Sender: no-reply@example.com
X-Mailer: Codeigniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <4ffbfbc917091@example.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_4ffbfbc9170e1"
```

In my inbox I get following details

```
Date: Tue, 10 Jul 2012 03:54:17 -0600
From: user@just61.justhost.com
Reply-To: "example.com" <no-reply@example.com>
X-Sender: no-reply@example.com
X-Mailer: codeigniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <4ffbfbc917091@example.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_4ffbfbc9170e1"
X-Identified-User: {:just61.justhost.com:user:just61.justhost.com} {sentby:program running on server}
```

Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Justhost was doing this crazy they need valid email address which was created to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but it still shows up in google searches pretty close to the top.  So yes the email address needs to exist on the server.  and also this.  https://my.justhost.com/hosting/help/206

Comment: Don't just repeat what someone else said and post a link. Try to constructively add something to the discussion